# PHP / MYSql to sort database entries by name, date, alpha, etc

Tags: php, mysql

Are there any off-the-shelf scripts that will display the results of a mysql query with clickable table headers to sort (and reverse sort) each column of data? This doesn't seem too hard to code myself, but I'm wondering if there are any good functions or libraries that already achieve this.

Comment: I'd recommend that you look at the tablesorter plugin for jquery: http://tablesorter.com/docs/

Comment: Wow - awesome plug-in, thanks! But I'm wondering if there's anything like that for the back-end instead of the front-end.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://datatables.net/

Answer (score 0):

There are libraries, which accomplish this, but they not PHP, but Javascript. One example would be "sortable", which you can get here: http://www.kryogenix.org/code/browser/sorttable/